# I have an error when creating the token with the library "firebase/token-php"

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

Good morning, what happens to me is that I get an error when sending the token to firebase (FCM) to register my backend in Laravel and thus make unit tests this is my code:

```
$privateKey = <<<EOD
        -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCxWB0uP6TBAMcC
        xUGdxiSUoIM89REQ4u09sXJ3qNMmhNY8U/WCbIZvSOQ2kqAXpnrwNyz4FUZfcjJa
        zS+tFtjxEURevcgGq49rAhOGLUae4GQWoLgPcIF+QIxT+WsxKkubgkLolIiocPpb
        fnzalZx2x9UzmjKwVydOV42EMm9xhktVaF6fUcZuNRVljXsecXye4bcCt3IawYk5
        0W+4ZRCUuSe5lGjGgDNZN6CI4R/1nwXauVXyppn4U+6YhtjH9dpjYpkgymzoKDnV
        UBZ8l1G3jouMuEUuBKzIEGIURYSb/ycVMU8hNevf0idMmt1mUgSJouXOGIguxzEK
        Rr6mBaefAgMBAAECggEAAl7g/zPFJcFToJh2/T80pk9MiOvJ8RzKHksOjvBfLxfo
        tXKEUActPm0/2Qzntw6NQ9I4GytNMOjg7/7LK79St2eSaDrq4sG3yFl27CBo7DRv
        IEzAsgHq8ThFViqypRFTSDApTOq4tn18k0JqNEp6eFg68jLO+zV40Ps4vlaXXgAo
        WTHTWZQG6GJNZXmPuzPgjEje63gQre90dCVP5Z0Hrea2mj4z5IEuAxAqkT3UN5m5
        -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
        EOD;

        $serviceAccount = "firebase-adminsdk-jf8q3@nkikku.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

        $now = now();

        $payload = [
                'iss' => $serviceAccount,
                'aud' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-jf8q3%40nnchat-qa.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
                'iat' => time(),
                'sub' => $serviceAccount,
                'exp' => time() + 3600, // Expira en una hora
                'uid' => "1", // Cambia esto con un ID de usuario real
            ];

        JWT::$leeway = 60;

        $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $privateKey, 'RS256');
        dump($jwt);
        return ValidateFirebaseNetwork::validateFirebase($jwt);
```

and the code to validate my token on fcm is:

```
$header = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . env('FCM_SERVER_KEY'),
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

        $message = array(
            'body' => trans('auth.verified_account'),
            'title' => trans('auth.verified_account'),
            'sound' => 'default'
        );

        $fields = array(
            KeyFirebaseValue::KEY_REGISTRATION_IDS => [$firebaseId],
            KeyFirebaseValue::KEY_NOTIFICATION => $message,
            KeyFirebaseValue::KEY_DATA => [
                KeyFirebaseValue::KEY_TIPE_NOTIFICATION => 5
            ],
            KeyFirebaseValue::KEY_PRIORITY => 'high',
            KeyFirebaseValue::KEY_CONTENT_AVAILABLE => true
        );

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array(
            $curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($fields),
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header
            )
        );
        
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $res1 = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        Log::debug($response);
        Log::info($res1);

        curl_close($curl);

        return intval(json_decode($response, true)[KeyFirebaseValue::RESPONSE_SUCCESS]);
```

and the error that firebase throws me is "InvalidRegistration", and I don't know what it can be, please help me.

I tried changing the email access keys to FCM but they all throw the same error, I know that if the token is successful the FCM response will be successful because my back can send messages through the firebase api.

Comment: ... `BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` ... Bruh

Comment: The private key is edited for security